# Overlay extending to the end of physical line

Tags: overlays

I'm trying to use overlay to highlight a whole line but for some reason my overlay stops at the end of the line (past the last character) instead of the end of the physical line (just before fringe). I'm certainly missing something obvious. Using the code below, `;; Test`  is highlighted
but I would have expected `;; Test`                                              .

```
;; Test

(save-excursion
  (goto-char 0)
  (let ((beg (point-at-bol))
        (end (min (point-max) (+ 1 (point-at-eol)))))
    (overlay-put (make-overlay beg end)
                 'face '(:background "#f0f0f0"))))
```

**Update** Answer given by @rpluim, I need to add a `:extend t` in the face definition.

Comment: `point-at-eol` tells you where the last character on the line is. Why would you expect it to give you the rightmost character position of the window?

Comment: Also I'd read about the `:extend` face attribute which is new in emacs-27

Comment: Tested it and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in emacs-27 you can specify the `:extend t` attribute when creating the face, and the background will then extend to the right edge of the Emacs window.