# Leuven (and some other themes) show wrong code block background

Tags: org-mode

Using emacs on Windows 10. The background colors of the begin, end, and code blocks don't continue to the ends of their lines. Since my .emacs file is rather short, I'll include it, too. Here's a picture:

[image: THe issue]

The .emacs file:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Fira Code Retina" :height 120)
(load-theme 'tango-dark)

;; Disable blinking cursor
(blink-cursor-mode 0)

;; Initialize package sources
(require 'package)

;; package repositories
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                              ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                                             ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                                             ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

;; initializes the package system to be ready to be used
(package-initialize)

;; a computer with a fresh install may not have a package archive
;; if there isn't one, refresh package list to make one
(unless package-archive-contents 
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Install use-package if it's not installed
;(require 'use-package)
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

(use-package doom-themes
  :config
  ;; Global settings (defaults)
  (setq doom-themes-enable-bold t    ; if nil, bold is universally disabled
        doom-themes-enable-italic t) ; if nil, italics is universally disabled
  (load-theme 'doom-one t)

  ;; Enable flashing mode-line on errors
  (doom-themes-visual-bell-config)
  
  ;; Enable custom neotree theme (all-the-icons must be installed!)
  (doom-themes-neotree-config)
  ;; or for treemacs users
  (setq doom-themes-treemacs-theme "doom-colors") ; use the colorful treemacs theme
  (doom-themes-treemacs-config)
  
  ;; Corrects (and improves) org-mode's native fontification.
  (doom-themes-org-config))

;; Download Evil if not installed
(unless (package-installed-p 'evil)
  (package-install 'evil))

;; Enable Evil
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

;; active Babel languages
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((java       . t)
   (python     . t)
;   (sh         . t)
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (dot        . t)
   (css        . t)
   (C          . t)))

;; bidirectional writing
(defun set-bidi-env ()
  "interactive"
  (setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'nil))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-bidi-env)

;; custom-set-variables works properly only if there's one instance of it

;; adds syntax highlighting & removes
;; "do you want to execute" when typing C-c C-c
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil
      org-src-fontify-natively t
      org-src-tab-acts-natively t)

(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)

(require 'org-bullets)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))


(defun my-bash-on-windows-shell ()
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe"))
    (shell)))
(my-bash-on-windows-shell)

;; double the size of preview latex in org
(setq org-format-latex-options
      (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 2.0))
```

Comment: Does [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62357/overlay-extending-to-the-end-of-physical-line/62361#62361) help?

Comment: @NickD Where would I need to put that?

Comment: I don't know: I would open an issue about it with the Leuven package and see if they will fix it.